# 'Collection property 'System.Windows.Documents.ListItem'.'SiblingListItems' is null. When I am loading xaml using Xamlservices.Load()

Tags: wpf, xaml, serialization

I have an Xaml file which contains Flow document & List Item inside that Xaml File.
            here is my code,

```
            xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";

            <Book>
              <Ins>
                 <p:FlowDocument>
                    <p:List StartIndex="1">
                        <p:ListItem>
                           <p:Paragraph>Some Text.</p:Paragraph>
                        </p:ListItem>
                        <p:ListItem>
                            <p:Paragraph>Some Text.</p:Paragraph>
                        </p:ListItem>
                    </p:List>
                 </p:FlowDocument>
              </Ins>
            </Book>

     private FlowDocument _notes;
        public FlowDocument Notes
                {            
                    get { return _notes; }
                    set
                    {
                        if (_notes!= value)
                        {
                            _notes= value;
                            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Notes);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I am able to load this document.. When I am trying to save this document by using XamlServices.Save, It is generating the below extra tags inside **List**..

```
  <av:List.SiblingBlocks>
         <x:Reference>__ReferenceID13</x:Reference>
    </av:List.SiblingBlocks>
  <av:ListItem.SiblingListItems>
       <x:Reference>__ReferenceID9</x:Reference>
              <x:Reference>__ReferenceID12</x:Reference>
</av:ListItem.SiblingListItems>
```

When I am trying to Load this newly saved Xaml file, it is throwing an error 
"Collection property 'System.Windows.Documents.ListItem'.'SiblingListItems' is null." at Sibling blocks..

I think my issue here is using Flow document as it is wpf typed object I can not use flow document (Wpf typed object) with XamlServices.Load()... 
Can I have any alternative for Flow document (Which is of not a wpf typed object)...

I also tried with XamlWriter.Save but It does not work for me as I am using Genric class with parameteral constructor..

Thanks in Advance..